# Ajax call in react native .Cant find variable: res

Tags: ajax, react-native

I'm trying make a ajax request for my react native app to my node.js server but when I load the app on expo it gave me an error "Can't find variable: res".

```
import React from 'react'
    import {
        ScrollView,
        StyleSheet,
        View,
    } from 'react-native';
    import Card from '../components/Card'
    import CardList from '../components/CardList'
    
    export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                error: null,
                isLoaded: false,
                items: []
            };
        }
    
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'Menu',
        };
        componentDidMount() {
            fetch("https://127.0.0.1:4001/menu")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(
                    (result) => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            items: result.items
                        });
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                            error
                        });
                    }
                )
        }
    
    
        render() {
            if (res) {
                return <View><Text>Error: {error.message}</Text></View>;
            } else if (!isLoaded) {
                return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
            } else {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
                            <View >
                                <CardList title={'Pizzas'}>
                                    {pizza.map(pizza => (<Card style={styles.card} name={pizza.name} description={pizza.decs} />))}
                                </CardList>
                                <CardList title={'others'}>
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                    <Card style={styles.card} />
                                </CardList>
    
                            </View>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <View style={styles.headerContainer}></View>
                    </View>
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried the URL in postman and it worked fine
[image]

I copied this mostly out of https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

anything helps, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurred because you are using `res` variable without declaration. In place of res inside render you need to use `this.state.error` inside if block.

You also need change pizza with this.state.items